# How can I determine the funders of an article?

Tags: funding

Who funded the article "randomized controlled trial contrasting the effect of 4 low calories sweeteners and sucrose on body weight in adults with overweight or obesity "? In general, how can I determine the funders of research articles?

Comment: hi and welcome to Academia.StackExchange. What have you done so far to answer that question? what exactly do you mean by "fund"? Please edit your question to get higher-quality answers. And please add link to the article on the journal's website if possible

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can find often find the sponsor listed in an article acknowledgement or registration of the protocol. The article was preregistered as NCT02928653. Upon going to the preregistration site I see the sponsor is Purdue University.